# Kendo UI Chart zoom event listener return empty axis range

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I need the updated values on the x-axis after the user zooms in. Based on an example I found (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fbwjp?file=app/app.component.ts) I could use the zoom event listener.

documentation for Kendo UI for zoom in:

from the image here, you can see that the axis ranges are coming back as and empty object {}.
why is this happening and how can I fix this ?

My end goal is to use the zoomed in range to update the data and redraw the graph

[image]

```log
ZoomEvent {sender: ChartComponent, prevented: false, axisRanges: {…}, delta: undefined, originalEvent: {…}}
axisRanges:
__proto__: Object
delta: undefined
originalEvent: {distance: 0, event: PointerEvent, target: path, touches: Array(1), preventDefault: ƒ, …}
prevented: false
sender: ChartComponent {configurationService: ConfigurationService, axisLabelClick: EventEmitter, drag: EventEmitter, dragEnd: EventEmitter, dragStart: EventEmitter, …}
__proto__: PreventableEvent
```

```html
<kendo-chart [pannable]="{ lock: 'y' }" [zoomable]="{ mousewheel :{ lock: 'y'}, selection: { lock: 'y' } }" (zoom)="onZoom($event)"
    [axisDefaults]="axisDefaults" [chartArea]="chartAreaOptions" [legend]="legendOptions">

    <kendo-chart-series>
      <!-- Loop thru all readings -->
      <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let readings of ReadingsData" [data]="readings.items"
        [color]="seriesOptionsArr.get(readings.value).color" [markers]="{ visible: false }"
        [name]="seriesOptionsArr.get(readings.value).name" type="scatterLine" xField="timeRead" yField="sample"
        zIndex="1">
      </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-x-axis>
      <kendo-chart-x-axis-item type="date" baseUnit="seconds" [min]="xAxisMin"
        [max]="xAxisMax" majorTicksVisible=false>
      </kendo-chart-x-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-x-axis>
    <kendo-chart-y-axis>
      <kendo-chart-y-axis-item ...>
      </kendo-chart-y-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-y-axis>

  </kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the axes needs to have a name. Once a name is added as follows the axisRange is added to the event information.

```html
      <kendo-chart-x-axis-item type="date" baseUnit="seconds" [labels]="{ format: getAxisDateFormat()}"
        [majorGridLines]="{ visible: false }"
        [minorGridLines]="{ visible: false }" [min]="xAxisMin"
        [max]="xAxisMax" majorTicksVisible=false name='date_axis'>
      </kendo-chart-x-axis-item>
```

eg.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2cvrw?file=app/app.component.ts